# Make text appear and disappear in processing

Tags: text, processing

So, I was wondering if there was a way to have text appear and then disappear as its being replaced by a different text. I currently found a code that will let me have text appear slowly one by one but I don't know the code that will let me get rid of the previous text as the new text appears. Please help me!

```
// creates the window with white background
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioSnippet snip;
color c1 = color(0,0,0), c2 = color(0,0,0), current;

void setup(){
  size(1200, 800);
  current = c1;
  smooth();
  minim = new Minim(this);
  snip = minim.loadSnippet("LoudGun.mp3");
}

void mousePressed() {
  snip.play();
if(current==c1) { current = c2; } else { current = c1; }
}

// draw "Charlotte"  
void CharlotteBacon() {
  frameRate(5);
  fill(255);
  textSize(50);
  text("Charlotte Bacon, Age 6", 600, 275);
}

// draw "Daniel" 
void DanielBarden() {
  frameRate(5);
  fill(255);
  textSize(50);
  text("Daniel Barden, Age 7", 20, 50);
}

int col = 0;
// main method where all above methods are executed on the white window
void draw() {
   background(current);
  if(mouseX != pmouseX && mouseY != pmouseY){

  }
  if (mousePressed) { 

  }
  // each phrase is printed at intervals of 2 seconds
  if (mouseX == pmouseX && mouseY == pmouseY && mousePressed != true) {
    ;
    int currentTime = millis();
    int timeLapse = 2000;
    if (currentTime > timeLapse) {
      CharlotteBacon();
    }
    if (currentTime > timeLapse*2) {
      DanielBarden();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is have a String holding the text to be displayed, and assign to it the text you want to display, so it will replace it.
I made and example, based on time as your code is.

```
String oneName = "Carol";
String otherName = "Chartllote";
String displayed ="";

int interval = 2000; // 2s
int time;

PFont font;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  font = createFont("arial", 26);
  background(0);
  displayed = oneName;
  time = millis();
  textFont(font);
  fill(255);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  text(displayed, width/2 - textWidth(displayed)/2, height/2);
  if (millis() - time > interval) {
    displayed = displayed.equals(oneName)? otherName:oneName;
    time  = millis();
  }
}
```